# Eloqua API Full Code Example in JAVA

Tags: java, api, web-services

**Is there anyone out there who has mastered to retrieve some data programmatically from Eloqua?**

First of all, I'm more or less a newbie, as far as JAVA. I can follow tutorials, take directions and will Google till my fingers bleed. I understand the basics and am slightly familiar with OOP. My main problem is that I have a Friday deadline (and tomorrow is Thanksgiving).

At any rate, all the Eloqua code snippets (that I've been able to find) illustrate one aspect of a specific issue, and that's it.

In my case, **I would greatly appreciate a JAVA project of some sort**, with all the necessary files to do web services (WSDL, SOAP and perhaps WSIT) and the main class and all that included.

No, I don't want you to do my work for me! Just give me enough to find my way around, enter the information I need to retrieve and all that. I'll take it from there.

Any pointers, links or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's been a while but here are some projects on GitHub that may offer some guidance:

- [Ruby: landcentral/eloqua](https://github.com/landcentral/eloqua)
- [JavaScript (Node.js): Eloqua/eloqua-request](https://github.com/Eloqua/eloqua-request)

There is also [a TopLiner article going into some detail](http://topliners.eloqua.com/community/do_it/blog/2011/04/05/using-eloqua-ws-api-with-java--part-1) with Java and Eclipse. [It was noted](http://topliners.eloqua.com/message/8834) that there may be some issues with it and the comments indicate possible paths to take to fix them.